# How to prove that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 - 2n + 3}$ converges?

Tags: calculus

Basically title. Don't worry, you are not doing my homework. I'm preparing for a calc exam right now and I've always wondered how to prove something like this, since you can't just do a direct comparison with the series with 1/n^2.

Comment: The "Limit Comparison Test" works on this.

Comment: $$
n^2  - 2n + 3 > \frac{1}{2}n^2  \Longrightarrow \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n^2  - 2n + 3}}}  < 2\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n^2 }}} 
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the limit comparison test, since it behaves asymptotically as $\frac{1}{n^2}$. Now clearly $\frac{1}{n^2-2n+3}\geq 0$ for all $n$ big enough, so we are justified in using it. Then

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n^2-2n+3}}{\frac{1}{n^2}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{n^2-2n+3}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{1-\frac{2}{n}+\frac{3}{n^2}}=1.$$

Thus, as

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$$

converges, so does

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2-2n+3}.$$